# Query with distinct and group by

Tags: mysql, group-by

[image]

How do I get 9,300 only out of the table above? I just need to add 6500 + 1800 + 1000

Here is my current query

```
SELECT 
SUM(e.amount) / (SELECT count(e2.receipt_no) 
                 FROM entries e2 
                 WHERE e2.receipt_no = e.receipt_no) as total,
e.user_id
FROM
entries e
GROUP BY e.receipt_no
```

The result is

[image]

Now i need to get the total per `user_id`

Expected output should be

[image]

Comment: plz show the expected output you required

Comment: `GROUP BY  DISTINCT e.receipt_no`

Comment: @JaydipJ It says mysql error when adding distinct in group by

Comment: ok `GROUP BY  e.receipt_no,User_id` i think you need tto group data by this two columns

Comment: Tried that but same result :(

Comment: plz add userid in the first image

Comment: @Shibon updated thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding this should give you want you want

`SELECT sum(DISTINCT amount) as total, reciept_no FROM entries GROUP BY receipt_no`

Answer (score 1):

Try some thing like this

```
SELECT SUM(DISTINCT(amount)) as total, user_id FROM `entries` GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Thank you this works for this scenario, how about for 2 receipts with same amount :(

Comment: The above query will sum the unique amount for each user

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 SELECT SUM(amount) as total,user_id FROM entries GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: sorry but it sums up all the amount from the rows from a user but i need to get the distinct amount first from a receipt then sum it with the amount from the other receipt.

Answer (score 1):

First calculate  DISTINCT amount group by  userid,receipt_no and then sum of there entries group by user_id:

```
SELECT sum(total),userid from (SELECT sum(DISTINCT amount) as total, 
userid,receipt_no FROM entries GROUP BY userid,receipt_no) as rgrouped 
GROUP BY userid
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this

```
SELECT  user_id, SUM(DISTINCT `amount`) FROM `test` group by `user_id`
```

Step 1: Select distinct amount for each user id

```
101 -  6500,1800,1000 
189 - 1019.00
```

Step - 2

```
101 = 6500+1800+1000 = 9300.00
189 = 1019.00
```

This will select `distinct` amount for each user id and then add selected amount and give you same result.